# Обязательно ли в типе параметра функции/процедуры указывать длину?

Tags: mysql

Обязательно ли при указании типа параметра функции или хранимой процедуры указывать длину?
Например, есть хранимая процедура:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_procedure`
(the_first_arg BIGINT(20), 
the_secong_arg DECIMAL(12,2), 
the_third_arg VARCHAR(10), 
the fourth_arg INT(5))
...
```

Изменится ли что-либо, если переписать её следующим образом?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_procedure`
(the_first_arg BIGINT, 
the_secong_arg DECIMAL, 
the_third_arg VARCHAR, 
the fourth_arg INT)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не указывать в параметре длину переменной, то будет подставлено дефолтное значение. Например, если не указывать длину для INT, то будет автоматом выставлено INT(11).